# Can't assign type any to string in Typescript, but i am trying to assign a string value

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, material-ui

I am a newbie in typescript and learning about how types work in Typescript.

I am also using `MaterialUI`in this project.

I am getting an error saying I am trying to assign an `any` value to a `string` variable. But I am trying to give a `string` value to a `string` variable.

Let me explain my project:

Here I am receiving a JSON from another folder
`import ProjectData from  '../../../../data/projectData.json';`

Here I am trying to map over ProjectData JSON file, and passing `Project` to an onClick handler

```
{ProjectData.map((Project) => { 
return ( <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Box onClick={() => { handleCardClick(Project)}}>
             ....
```

Here is my handleCardClick function:

```
const handleCardClick = (Project: ProjectJSONData) => {
    setSelectedProject({
        projectTitle: {Project.projectTitle},
        thumbnail:    {Project.projectThumbnail},
        userName:     {Project.username},
        profileImage: {Project.userProfileImage},
        openToCollab: {Project.openToCollab},
        tags:         {Project.tags},
    })
};
```

and my useState:
`const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState<ProjectDataType | null>(null);`

These are the two types I have defined:

`ProjectJSONData` is for the JSON I am receiving

```
type ProjectJSONData = {
    projectTitle: string;
    ProjectThumbnail: string;
    username: string;
    userProfileImage: string;
    openToCollab: string;
    tags: string[];
};
```

`ProjectDataType` is a custom one I have made.

```
type ProjectDataType = {
    projectTitle: string;
    thumbnail: string;
    userName: string;
    profileImage: string;
    openToCollab: boolean;
    tags: string[];
};
```

I am getting my error at the definition of `handleCardClick`.

Comment: This `projectTitle: {Project.projectTitle}` is not valid javascript or typescript syntax. Did you mean to do `projectTitle: Project.projectTitle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
projectTitle: {Project.projectTitle}
```

is not valid javascript or typescript syntax. The `{ }` there don't do what you think they do.

You want this:

```
const handleCardClick = (Project: ProjectJSONData) => {
    setSelectedProject({
        projectTitle: Project.projectTitle,
        thumbnail:    Project.ProjectThumbnail,
        userName:     Project.username,
        profileImage: Project.userProfileImage,
        openToCollab: Project.openToCollab,
        tags:         Project.tags,
    })
};
```

Additionally, `openToCollab` is `string` in one type, and `boolean` in the other.

And lastly, you use `Project.projectThumbnail` but the type has that declared with a capital `P`, so you must use `Project.ProjectThumbnail`.

With those changes, everything works fine.

[See working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=32&ssc=3&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAsAFBswCeYBACuQCt0jAFKYA8gDkAInhxwAvIjZxVcMIOEwAKsBgAbdAC44qGFGAA7AOYBuFWv4QhjbQAtkIAEaWcwfSZmFjb2rGooGFC+IMam5lZ2Dqpo6FBOJP7oAJIgONaxQQmh4RA8ltoQAMIQ+vo4XiZeEDV0lsVquNaogfE2ANoAuqGEoRzcfJqMsrja44rKYWoazlq6BgW9iYuqMB7evv49wVvhKVCSODFHRUnq5BmGOXkbx+2qpejlVTV1DXBNLRwbVunW6cWOg2Go1Y9AgljMcD6GEMjHQABMnC4YAAaUzoGCYdAo-AYyYwAbzFLYPDoAA8mK00xwsx4cAAPnBLMhagA+AAUXNqAEpobD4fA3EC0YZKjgoGjKvpgPQANbzPkMxgmTUwMRSJlCxQ8hbhDAEoladE6vkIW7hZZYtaGbVkgB0DtWekM2LtHT2Pj8AXCOtdOvcngD-h923CEVSFyusZDZ2i6GjsaW90yT3yLpWjFdZ3S2dy+XTGbgHy+1Vq9TzWNdVYqNd+5YzoJMFbgIdBbaIQrYIyAA)

Comment: yes i was making that syntax error

Answer (score 1):

On `ProjectDataType`, you have `openToCollab` type as `boolean`
. On `ProjectJSONData`, you have `openToCollab` type as `string`

Comment: yes that was also a mistake from my side